# Reference the detault suite teardown, in a case's custom[Teardown]

Tags: robotframework

Is it possible - and if yes, how - to call default teardown defined in the suite, when you've overriding it in a specific test case?

Example:

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup         Setup The Environment
Test Teardown       Clean The System

*** Test Cases ***
Test the thing
    Do something
    Create an object

    [Teardown]     Delete the object             # at this point the suite's test case teardown is overriden, "Clean The System" will not be called
```

The question is there an internal reference to the suite-level Test Teardown, or a setting to force its execution after any custom teardowns in test cases - apart from the obvious

```
Run Keywords    Delete the object    AND   Clean The System
```

The latter shifts the responsibility to the person creating the test cases, and can be easily overlooked - esp. in a large suite/long list of keywords.

Comment: Seems an XY-problem. What do you want to do?

Comment: @Alex.S - enforce the usage of the teardown set on the Settings level, w/o explicitly calling it in each and every test case where it is overriden.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to do what you want. Your obvious solution is the only solution.

Comment: I also regretfully didn't find anything in the docs (and a fast glimpse in the source), thus asking here